# What does <any> mean infront of an Typescript class constructor argument?

Tags: angular, typescript, typing

I am reading the [Angular - Testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing) documentation. When describing how to test asynchronous *services* (Testing HTTP services) I encountered a class constructor with an `<any>` in front of the passed argument. The complete line is given by

`heroService = new HeroService(<any> httpClientSpy);`

I know, that `any` in Typescript stands for literally "any" type. What are the guillemets (`<...>`) used for? And why is the typing in front of the argument? Is it used for type parsing?

---

The full code from the documentation:

```
let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
let heroService: HeroService;

beforeEach(() => {
  // TODO: spy on other methods too
  httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
  heroService = new HeroService(<any> httpClientSpy);
});

it('should return expected heroes (HttpClient called once)', () => {
  const expectedHeroes: Hero[] =
    [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];

  httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedHeroes));

  heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
    heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'expected heroes'),
    fail
  );
  expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'one call');
});

it('should return an error when the server returns a 404', () => {
  const errorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
    error: 'test 404 error',
    status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found'
  });

  httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncError(errorResponse));

  heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
    heroes => fail('expected an error, not heroes'),
    error  => expect(error.message).toContain('test 404 error')
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is type assertion.

> Originally the syntax that was added was `<foo>`. However, there is an ambiguity in the language grammar when using `<foo>` style assertions in JSX. Therefore it is now recommended that you just use `as foo` for consistency.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 0):

HeroService is being instantiated as a SpyObject

following the structure |Object

You can check in the Jasmine [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.createSpy)